# Counting the "latest" consecutive count in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a dummy dataset as below, it is a dataset that record the result of specimen taken from each patient:

```
case_id     specimen_type_id    virus_id    specimen_result specimen_collection_date
1           1                   4           positive        25/12/2014
1           1                   5           positive        25/12/2014
1           1                   4           negative        21/01/2015
1           2                   4           negative        21/01/2015
1           1                   4           negative        23/01/2015
1           2                   4           negative        23/01/2015
1           1                   4           positive        25/01/2015
1           1                   4           negative        26/01/2015
1           1                   4           negative        27/01/2015
1           1                   5           negative        27/01/2015
```

`case_id` refers to the ID of the patient

`specimen_type_id` refers to the type of the specimen taken, whether it is a blood sample, sputum sample, etc

`virus_id` is the type of virus that we are looking for

`specimen_result` is whether the specimen has found the virus (positive) or not (negative)

`specimen_collection_date` is when that specimen is taken.

I need a list showing each patient: i) the latest consecutive negative specimen count (i.e. a positive result in the middle and it needs to be counted all over again), ii) latest date for the latest consecutive negative specimen. Something like this below:

```
case_id virus_id    specimen_type_id    count   latest_specimen_collection_date
1       4           1                   2       27/01/2015
1       5           1                   1       27/01/2015
```

The output the based on the last 3 rows of the dataset in my example.

I am a newbie to MySQL, I searched `MySQL consecutive` and the codes are a bit cryptic to me, can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: It's because relational databases are not designed for searching for "consecutive" stuff. What you need to do is to `JOIN` a table to itself with date >= current row date and with result = negative, then just take the earliest date.

Comment: @zerkms you solved the date problem, but what about the count problem?

Answer (score 0):

The following query goes most of the way to solve your problem.  It creates a row by row list of 'runs' of consecutive identical results for a particular case, virus and speciman type.

```
set @runn = 0;
set @runv = 'xxx';
SELECT specruns.*,count(*) cnt,MIN(specruns.speciman_date) mindate,MAX(specruns.speciman_date) maxdate 


  FROM
(
SELECT

IF(@runv = CONCAT(s.case_id,s.speciman_type_id,s.virus_id,s.speciman_result ) ,@runn,@runn:=@runn+1) run,
@runv := CONCAT(s.case_id,s.speciman_type_id,s.virus_id ,s.speciman_result) val,

 s.* FROM specs s
ORDER BY s.case_id,s.speciman_type_id,s.virus_id ,s.speciman_date
) specruns
GROUP BY specruns.run
```